# I'd appreciate help understanding this proof about the general solution to an exact differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

all. I am working through Annin and Goode's "Differential Equations and Linear Algebra", specifically on the section about exact differential equations. They have a proof for the following theorem:

> The general solution to an exact equation
>           
> $$
>               M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0 
> $$
>        is defined implicitly by 
>
>            $$
>        \phi(x,y) = c
>        $$
> where φ(x,y) is a function such that 
>
> $ \dfrac{\partial \phi}{ \partial x }= M$ and $ \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = N $
> for all x,y in region R

The proof begins

> We re-write the differential equation in the form
> $$   M(x,y) + N(x,y) \dfrac{dy}{dx} =0$$
>
> Since the differential equation is exact, there exists a potential function $ \phi$ such that 
>
> $$
>   \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0
> $$
>
> But this implies that $\partial\phi/ \partial x =0$. Consequently, $\phi(x,y)$ is a function of y only. By a similar argument, which we leave to the reader, we can deduce that $\phi(x,y)$ is a function of x only. We conclude therefore that $\phi(x,y)=c$, where c is a constant

I understand the argument they're trying to make, i.e., if I accept the statement 'But this implies that $\partial\phi/ \partial x =0$.' Where I'm getting hung up is accepting this statement. Why, exactly, is it true?

I should add, I understand that the conclusion is true, because

$$
  \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}
$$

is the same as $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\phi(x,y))$ and if this equals zero, then the function $\phi(x,y)$ must be a constant.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure they printed the partial differential symbols and not the total differential? This seems to be a misprint. As they are considering the derivatives of $ϕ(x,y(x))$, there is no independent $y$ variable that the constant could depend on. The whole argument seems somewhat rushed. Your idea is right.

Comment: I think this arose form the *exact form* that is $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$
then $\dfrac{\partial \phi}{ \partial x }dx+\dfrac{\partial \phi}{ \partial y}dy=0$ and $$d\phi(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial \phi}{ \partial x }dx+\dfrac{\partial \phi}{ \partial y}dy=0$$

Comment: @LutzL, I'm sure. In fact, I had it opened in front of me as I typed the question out. I agree, it seems rushed, as do many of the explanations in this particular book. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @MyGlasses  I think I understand. In that case, then would $\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$ also equal zero? Is that what is meant by 'by a similar argument'? Thank you.

Comment: That would be strange, as $\frac{∂ϕ}{∂y}=N(x,y)$ so that coefficient would have to be zero. If also $0=\frac{∂ϕ}{∂x}=M(x,y)$, then you have no differential equation left.

Comment: @LutzL I see your point. I'm gonna sleep on it. Thanks for all the help from both of you.